# Breaking out of then promise chain

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I break out of Promise chain (deal with error and stop running other .then's)?

My code:

```
onSubmit(f: any) {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Sending a form...'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.submitProvider.sendByPost(f)
    .then(
        (res) => { this.formSent = true, console.log('Form is sent') },
        (err) => { console.log('Encountered an error...') 
            //error here, break out and deal with error            
        } 
    )
    .then( (res) => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.pushPage(); 
        this.removeChosenPicture();
        this.removeTakenPicture();
        this.myForm.reset({ selectedDate: this.selectedDate }) }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `catch()` method: By doing this you will handle any errors from you promise chain. when an error is throw anywhere in your chain it will "break" from the promise chain and end up in the catch method. [MDN: .catch() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
onSubmit(f: any) {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Sending a form...'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.submitProvider.sendByPost(f)
    .then(
        (res) => { this.formSent = true, console.log('Form is sent') }
    )
    .then( (res) => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.pushPage(); 
        this.removeChosenPicture();
        this.removeTakenPicture();
        this.myForm.reset({ selectedDate: this.selectedDate }) }
    ).catch((err) =>{ /*Handle your errors*/})
}
```